# Building a DAG such that nodes are reused

Tags: haskell, graph, functional-programming, directed-acyclic-graphs, idris

I want to build a DAG, but am unsure how to do it without duplicating effort when evaluating it.

I started with an AST like

```
data Node =
    Lit Double
  | Neg Node
  | Add Node Node
```

but traversing `let x = Lit 1.0 in Add x x` evaluates* `x` twice. I came up with a few approaches but all have problems.

*it's been pointed out in the comments that I might not mean evaluate in the usual sense. I'm using this to construct a graph in C++ with XLA.

**Approach 1: Cache evaluated nodes**

Cache evaluated nodes then re-use them where nodes compare equal. This is inefficient because the user knows which nodes are re-used where, so it seems we should be able to use that information.

**Approach 2: Topological sort**

I tried a topological sort (is it a topological sort?) `List Node` with

```
data Node =
    Lit Double
  | Neg Nat
  | Add Nat Nat
```

so I can represent the previous example as `[Lit 1.0, Add 0 0]`. That works fine, but I don't know how to construct this list.

In the above example it's trivial, but it gets messy when I have graphs like

```
   Lit 1.0
      |
     Neg  Lit 2.0
      | \ /
      | Add
      | /
      Add
```

because it's not clear while I'm constructing it how to order the nodes in the list. (It's obvious how to order the nodes if you can see the whole graph, but I can't while I'm constructing it.)

**Approach 2a: Topological sort with global state**

If I was using an imperative language I could use a global state that adds nodes as they're created. Translating mutable state to a functional setting, I immediately thought of the `State` monad, but I'm wrapping this functionality and I don't want to expose monadic computations to users: I want them to do

```
let x = val 1.0
    y = x + x
 in y + y
```

not

```
do x <- val 1.0
   y <- x + x
   y + y
```

I wonder if referential transparency directly means I can't do this because expressions should be replaceable by their value.

**Approach 2b: Topological sort - merging subgraphs**

Use a topological sort, but build component graphs separately, then merge them when I meet a node that combines graphs, such as `Add`. I'm not clear how to do this. I could test nodes for equality, but like in the first approach, this seems a waste, as we're forgetting what's re-used where then recalculating it.

I'm doing this in Idris, but I imagine it's the same in Haskell.

Comment: I think you are trying to address something that's beyond the scope of your AST. `Lit 1.0` is already, in some sense, as evaluated as it can be.

Comment: @chepner by evaluating it I may mean compiling. I'm not too strong on the lingo. In my case, I'm compiling this to another graph representation in C++, running that graph, and converting it into a `Double`. In full detail, everything's a tensor, and I'm compiling to XLA then back to a separate custom native Idris array type.

Comment: Could you explain what's goin wrong??. In the expresion  `let {x = val 1.0;  y = x + x} in y + y` both `x` and `y` are evaluated once (AFAIK) and reused on each reference. When you are compiling this to C++, are you getting the wrong result?? how do you compile it?

Comment: OK, either this is a problem for your code generator to solve, or you need a richer AST (to allow something like `Let (Symbol 'x') (Lit 1.0) (Add (Symbol 'x') (Symbol 'x'))` to guide the code generator.

Comment: @chepner ok that looks interesting but i'm not entirely following. How would I apply that to the more complicated example above `(-1 + (-1 + 2))` where I reuse a value indirectly? There I don't want to process `Neg (Lit 1.0)` twice. I'm also not sure what "this is a problem for your code generator to solve" entails

Comment: Because the AST represents the syntax only, not how you plan on computing what it represents. The code generator is the thing that worries about how to efficiently implement what your AST sees.

Comment: @lsmor I trace it backwards from `y`, which sees two instances of `x`, and adds two nodes to my C++ graph with value `1.0`, while I should only have one and refer to it twice. I see the right result, but it's inefficient.

Comment: @chepner so if I was to reproduce exactly what a user writes, I'd presumably need to build the code generator at the same time as the AST if I am to remember more than just the AST, but how everything links up? I get the impression I'm asking pretty basic compiler theory qus here - I have no compiler experience.

Comment: Regarding `Neg (Lit 1.0)`, it's common to immediately collapse that to `Lit (-1.0)`. Just because you choose to let the parser, rather than the lexer, deal with negative literals doesn't mean you need to process that at run-time. Some optimizations can be done on the AST before you generate code.

Comment: Why is it important that the user write `let y = x + x in y + y` rather than `do { y <- x + x; y + y }`? The latter API is absolutely the obvious, idiomatic way to support the things you're trying to do.

Comment: This task is called “observable sharing”, if you want to search for more literature on it.

Comment: @DanielWagner because it's a tensor library and it's not idiomatic to pepper algebra with monadic syntax

Comment: @joel How many Haskell tensor libraries have you looked at before making this judgment?

Comment: @DanielWagner none in depth. I meant it's not idiomatic in maths. I believe it would also make complex expressions far more visually complex than they would otherwise be

Comment: @joel Idioms vary by language. In particular it's common for the idiomatic math thing to be very different from the idiomatic programming thing.

Answer (score 4):

You have, roughly speaking, two choices:

1. Represent sharing explicitly in your AST. This means adding a `Let` node to your graph. Like this:

   ```
   data Expr = Lit Double | Add Expr Expr | Var Int | Let Int Expr Expr
   ```

   For example, your `let x = 1; y = x+x in y+y` might look like

   ```
       Let 0 (Lit 1) (Let 1 (Add (Var 0) (Var 0)) (Add (Var 1) (Var 1)))
    -- let x = 1 in   let y = (+)     x       x in (+)      y       y
   ```

   For bonus points, use `MonadSupply` or similar to make it easy to allocate fresh variables, as in:

   ```
   do
       x <- fresh
       y <- fresh
       pure $ Let x (Lit 1) (Let y (Add (Var x) (Var x)) (Add (Var y) (Var y)))
   ```

   You could also add convenience functions for manipulating monadic expressions, as in

   ```
   type ExprM = Supply Int Expr

   lit :: Double -> ExprM
   add :: ExprM -> ExprM -> ExprM
   name :: ExprM -> (ExprM -> ExprM) -> ExprM
   name val fBody = do
       v <- fresh
       eVal <- val
       eBody <- fBody (var v)
       pure (Let v eVal eBody)
   ```

   Then the user could write, e.g.

   ```
   name (lit 1) $ \x -> name (add x x) $ \y -> add y y
   ```
2. Represent sharing externally to your AST -- this approach is often bundled with hash-consing.

   ```
   data ExprP = Lit Double | Add Int Int
   type Env = IntMap ExprP
   type IEnv = Map ExprP Int -- optional
   ```

   Here an expression only says what the top-level operation is; any subtrees are stored as pointers, which can be looked up in the associated `Env`. For example, your `let x = 1; y = x+x in y+y` is the pointer `2` into environment:

   ```
   fromList
       [ (0, Lit 1)
       , (1, Add 0 0)
       , (2, Add 1 1)
       ]
   ```

   For bonus points, use `State` to manage your environment, as in

   ```
   type Expr = State (Int, Env) Int
   allocPointer :: ExprP -> Expr
   allocPointer e = do
       (n, env) <- get
       put (n+1, insert n e env)
       pure n

   lit :: Double -> Expr
   lit = allocPointer . Lit

   add :: Int -> Int -> Expr
   add a b = allocPointer (Add a b)
   ```

   Then the user could write, say,

   ```
   do
       x <- lit 1
       y <- add x x
       add y y
   ```

   The optional inverse environment can be used to implement automatic sharing -- in `allocPointer`, when the user requests that you add `e` to the environment, you can look `e` up in the inverse environment and simply return the appropriate pointer instead of allocating a fresh one if it already exists. In that world, a user could write, say,

   ```
   do
       x <- lit 1
       y <- add x x
       z <- add x x
       add y z
   ```

   and this would automatically discover that `y` and `z` were the same (cheaply, i.e. without comparing the entire term for equality recursively, just by noticing that the top-level pointers were equal).

Comment: Thanks, there's a lot in here - will take me time to digest

Comment: do i understand correctly that both of these require explicit monadic behaviour at the user level, i.e. there's no way to hide this machinery?

Comment: that is, i'm obviously fine with using monadic approaches, I just want to hide it if possible

Comment: @joel You are doing a stateful thing. The easiest way to do stateful things is using the state monad family. Of course you are free to do everything with explicit `let` binding and manual tracking of the state, to avoid monads, but... yeah, don't do that.

Comment: i've confused things by talking about monads. What I mean is that I don't want users to see the sharing functionality, since it doesn't change the result of a computation, only the performance. I'm starting to realise what I want might just not be possible